# uninstall gnome-do plugins

Tags: ubuntu, plugins, gnome-do, synaptic-pkg-mgr

On ubuntu (actualy, linux mint + xfce)

I downloaded gnome-do-plugins package from synaptic, I got two problems with that package:

- it forced me to download a whole bunch of things I don't really want or need, such as evolution (why the hell is it even a dependency?)
- it started asking for keyring password (why?!?)

So, I removed the gnome-do-plugins package, but, it still asks for keyring password, and, gnome-do still lists all the plugins (except that now they can't be used).

I want to *really* remove the plugins, so that:

- They don't appear in the plugins list.
- It stops prompting me for keyring password.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try purging (remove package files *and configuration files*) both gnome-do and gnome-do-plugins packages and then reinstalling gnome-do ?

> sudo apt-get --purge remove gnome-do
>   gnome-do-plugins

.. followed by ..

> sudo apt-get autoclean

Then try reinstalling gnome-do. That should simulate a fresh install of gnome-do and hopefully remove this issue.

Comment: problem is, if I install gnome-do, it will install gnome-do-plugins with it

Comment: it should not install all the plugins.  You can install and uninstall them manually by right clicking on Gnome-DO > Preferences > Plugins