# How do I uninstall GNome DO?

Tags: ubuntu, gnome-do

How do I uninstall GNome DO? I had a look at [uninstall gnome-do plugins](https://superuser.com/questions/20222/uninstall-gnome-do-plugins) but this does not work for me? Any help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First check the output for,

```
sudo dpkg -l | grep gnome.do
```

And then, describe what happens when you do,

```
sudo apt-get remove gnome-do
```

Comment: I made a syntax error gnomedo and not gnome-do